# Ejercicio con fichero en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo que crear un programa que haga lo siguiente:
Leer los datos de un fichero de dos columnas coordenadas.txt, pedir por consola que el usuario introduzca un numero (n) y debe hacer la siguiente operación n*(x+y).
Por consola debe imprimir el resultado máximo que se obtiene al hacer esa operación con todas las coordenadas del fichero y los puntos en los que se obtiene ese resultado, si hay puntos repetidos solo tiene que salir una vez por consola.
Un ejemplo:
Si n = 1 y el fichero es:

```
1 1
2 1
4 5
3 6
6 3
8 1
0 0
3 6
4 3
```

Por consola debería aparecer: " La solucion maxima es 9 y se obtiene en los puntos (4,5), (3,6), (6,3), (8,1)"
Tengo hecho el código pero no consigo que salga por pantalla todos los puntos en los que se consigue ese resultado, solo me sale el ultimo punto en el que se obtiene 9.

Mi codigo es:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double n;
    std::cout << "Valor de n ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::ifstream in("coordenadas.txt",std::ios::in);
    double operacion, x_max, y_max;
    double op_max = INT_MIN;
    std::vector<double> x0,y0;
    while(!in.eof()){
        double X,Y;
        in >> X >> Y;
        operacion = n*(X+Y);
        if(operacion > op_max){
            op_max = operacion;
            x_max = X;
            y_max = Y;
            x0.clear();
            y0.clear();
            x0.push_back(X);
            y0.push_back(Y);
        }
        else if(operacion == op_max){
            for(int j = 0; j < x0.size(); j++){
                if(X == x0[j] && Y == y0[j])break;              
                else{               
                    op_max = operacion;
                    x_max = X;
                    y_max = Y;
                    x0.push_back(X);
                    y0.push_back(Y);
                }
            }
        }
    }   

    in.close();

    std::cout << "La solucion maxima es " << op_max << "\n Se alcanza en los puntos:";

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < x0.size(); i++){    
    std::cout << "\n (" << x0[i] << "," << y0[i] << ")"<< std::endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Por consola me aparece:

```
La solucion maxima es 9
Se alcanza en los puntos
(8,1)
(4,5)
(3,6)
(3,6)
(6,3)
(6,3)
(6,3)
(6,3)
(3,6)
(3,6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en el bucle for y en la condición else.

```
 else if(operacion == op_max){
        for(int j = 0; j < x0.size(); j++){
            if(X == x0[j] && Y == y0[j])break;              
            else{               
                op_max = operacion;
                x_max = X;
                y_max = Y;
                x0.push_back(X);
                y0.push_back(Y);
            }
        }
    }
```

Supongamos que vamos a leer una línea del fichero con pareja ( 8 1 ) y que anteriormente hayamos leído las parejas (4 5), (3 6) y ( 6 3 ), las cuales se encuentran insertadas en los vectores x0 e y0.

Si hacemos una traza del bucle for sería:

Desde j = 0 hasta j = 3 ( tamaño de x0 -> hay 3 inserciones).
Debido a que los valores son distintos a todos los insertados, siempre se va a cumplir la condición del else y por tanto va a insertar la pareja ( 8 1 ) 3 veces.

¿Cómo lo puedes solucionar? 
Por ejemplo, con un booleano:

```
 else if(operacion == op_max){
        bool coincidencia = false;

        for(int j = 0; j < x0.size(); j++){
            if(X == x0[j] && Y == y0[j]){
                coincidencia = true;
                break; 
            }
        }

        if ( coincidencia == false ){
            op_max = operacion;
            x_max = X;
            y_max = Y;
            x0.push_back(X);
            y0.push_back(Y);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

El error esta en el else, ya que tiene primero tienes que comprobar con todas las coordenadas ya estan en el vector, y si ninguna es igual, entonces a las coordenacas anteriores recien le agregamos, así recién agregar, sino se agrega varias bese los mismo por que el.

```
if(X == x0[j] && Y == y0[j])break;              
            else{               
                op_max = operacion;
                x_max = X;
                y_max = Y;
                x0.push_back(X);
                y0.push_back(Y);
            }
```

el if y else anterior esan en el mmismo for así que siempre se ejecutan, incluso cuando son iguales y se agregará. El else del codigo anterior debería ir fuera del for, así solo se agrega una ves comparadas con todos, adjunto el codigo, elimine y ordene un poco, pero el codigo es casi el mismo

una solución es usar una variable bandera para evaluar, si el valor X e Y ya se encuentran dentro, entonces hacemos ban == 0 ; break, eso significa que ya se ecuentra dentro pero ya terminado el for, caso contrario quiere decir que no esta por que ban == 1, y se agrega al final de evalución.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
double n;
std::cout << "Valor de n ";
std::cin >> n;

std::ifstream in("coordenadas_de_prueba.txt",std::ios::in);
double operacion;
double op_max = INT_MIN;
double X,Y;
std::vector<double> x0,y0;
int size_vector;

while(!in.eof()){
    in >> X >> Y;
    operacion = n*(X+Y);
    size_vector = x0.size();

    if(operacion > op_max){
        op_max = operacion;
        x0.clear();
        y0.clear();
        x0.push_back(X);
        y0.push_back(Y);                    
    }
    else if(operacion == op_max){   
        int ban = 1;        
        for(int j = 0; j < x0.size(); j++){
            if(X == x0[j] && Y == y0[j]){               
                ban = 0;
                break;              
            }
        }
        if (ban == 1){
            x0.push_back(X);
            y0.push_back(Y); 
        }
    }
}   

in.close();

std::cout << "La solucion maxima es " << op_max << "\n Se alcanza en los puntos:";

for(unsigned i = 0; i < x0.size(); i++){    
std::cout << "\n (" << x0[i] << "," << y0[i] << ")"<< std::endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

cambiar el nombre de archivo de las coordenadas.